# MS SQL SERVER - cast int to price format

Tags: sql-server

I have records like

```
Price 0
Price 23
Price 555
```

When I use SELECT ... cast(Price as decimal(10,2))

I get this weird error : if price is 0 = I get .00 not 0.00. All other variations work (23 goes to 23.00 as I would like). How to fix zeros?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked (and answered) before, but one option would be for you to just handle this in your presentation layer.

Comment: Looks like more of a database client setting

Comment: What is the type of Price ?

Comment: @ahmedabdelqader int

Comment: `declare @Price int
set @Price = 0
SELECT cast(@Price as decimal(10,2))` Result = `0.00` what is the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server >= 2012 you can use format:

```
declare @Price int = 0
select format(@Price, 'N') --General format
select format(@Price, 'C') --Currency format
```

Instead of variable you can use appropriate table columns in your table